# Facebook SDK 6.0 for Unity: I don't understand how permissions work

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-permissions

I seriously do not understand how the permissions work.
Let me explain:

1. I have a Facebook app set in my developer account
2. I have defined a test app
3. In my Unity app using the Facebook SDK, Im calling this login function:

   ```
   string permissions = "public_profile,user_bithday,user_location";
   FB.Login (permissions, LoginCallback);
   ```
4. After the callback, I'm asking for the granted permissions and I'm getting:

   ```
   request response: {"data":[{"permission":"public_profile","status":"granted"},{"permission":"email","status":"granted"},{"permission":"publish_actions","status":"granted"},{"permission":"user_birthday","status":"granted"},{"permission":"user_likes","status":"granted"},{"permission":"user_photos","status":"granted"},{"permission":"user_friends","status":"granted"}]}
   ```

I have to say that I'm still experimenting with the SDK making with the same Facebook app, different logins from different Unity projects (from the Editor of course). The permissions I am getting are the one I asked with a project I was developing 3 weeks ago. Because everything was working, I focused on something different. Today I made a new project by asking for the permissions defined in the login function in the point 3.

My question is: why am I getting permissions I didn't ask for?
Will I have the same problem when I'll deploy the app on different devices?
**[EDIT]
More important than those, why I'm not getting the permissions "user_location" I'm asking for? It's not even saying that the requested permission has been denied.
[/EDIT]**

The idea is to use the same Facebook app but with 2 different Unity projects: one project is a game that will be deployed on iOS and Android and another one is a standalone app for Mac and Windows that will allow the authorized person to modify the game (let's say a game editor). As you can guess, the projects will need different permissions. Is this something duable or because I'm using 2 different projects with the same Facebook app I'll have problems?

Cheers for the help guys  :-)

Comment: I don't know anything about Facebook permissions, but is it actually a problem to be granted permissions you didn't ask for? Presumably you would just parse the permissions response for the things you requested, see they were all granted and ignore everything else?

Comment: Well, I will not use any function for the permissions granted that I didn't ask, but the problem is that I need a permission that is not granted and , on top of that, the check will not tell me that it has not been granted. Usually if you ask a permission that has not granted there should be a "permission refused" notification that is not happening.

Comment: Got you. It might be clearer to make that explicit in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a user has granted a certain Facebook app permissions, they stay there unless the developer or the user explicitly take them away; The FB.Login() call is there to ensure that you have, at a minimum, the permissions you've requested.

Incidentally, Facebook recommends asking for permissions only at the exact point you need to use them; Asking for more permissions is done with FB.Login("just_the_new_permission_you_need") and it won't take away what the user gave thus far.

tl;dr yes, using two projects with the same appid means permissions from one will be granted to another and vice-versa.

Comment: gotcha. just another thing: I'm asking for all the permission I need in the first login, because what I actually need is to retrieve the info of the logged in user to fill the field of my app. is there any way to get them in the first call instead of checking what I got and ask again? this asking and re-asking has a cost if you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm afraid not; Facebook always gives the user the freedom to decide they do not want to give a developer certain permissions.

EDIT: It might help a lot to explain **why** you want permissions before asking for them instead of front-loading your app with the demand.

Comment: Oh yea, I know that. I will explain in details why I need a permission when I'll submit the app for approval. What I was asking was related about the first login call in the app. Let me explain better: if I need publish, email and location can I ask for those permissions in one go in my first login call or do I have to ask for the 3 of them in 3 different consecutive login calls? I suppose that I can ask for all of them in one go... but as I said I'm not getting the location in this case...

Comment: You can ask for them all in one go, but you _will_ need to check what the user actually gave you and then decide if you want to keep bugging them until you get it or give up.